# Adding table row with JavaScript with same drop down cells

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry in advance for the poor coding.

I've added a button to the bottom of a product ordering table that I'm working on which when clicked by the user adds an additional table row.

The button works and adds another row however I want it to add the row with the same dropdown cells above.

```html
<div>
  <table id="lst-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Model <br>Ref.</th>
        <th class="lst-th" scope="col">Perforation <br>Type         </th>
        <th class="lst-th" scope="col">LST Cover <br>Length
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="lst-tbody">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="">Model Ref.</option>
            <option value="145-520">ARM 145-520</option>
            <option value="145-670">ARM 145-670</option>
            <option value="145-820">ARM 145-820</option>
            <option value="145-920">ARM 145-920</option>
            <option value="165-520">ARM 165-520</option>
            <option value="165-670">ARM 165-670</option>
            <option value="165-820">ARM 165-820</option>
            <option value="165-920">ARM 165-920</option>
            <option value="180-520">ARM 180-520</option>
            <option value="180-670">ARM 180-670</option>
            <option value="180-820">ARM 180-820</option>
            <option value="180-920">ARM 180-920</option>
            <option value="200-520">ARM 200-520</option>
            <option value="200-670">ARM 200-670</option>
            <option value="200-820">ARM 200-820</option>
            <option value="200-920">ARM 200-920</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="">Perf Type</option>
            <option value="dd">DD</option>
            <option value="7d">7D</option>
            <option value="5s">5S</option>
            <option value="dmd">DMD</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="">Length</option>
            <option value="675">675</option>
            <option value="775">775</option>
            <option value="875">875</option>
            <option value="975">975</option>
            <option value="1075">1075</option>
            <option value="1175">1175</option>
            <option value="1275">1275</option>
            <option value="1375">1375</option>
            <option value="1475">1475</option>
            <option value="1575">1575</option>
            <option value="1675">1675</option>
            <option value="1775">1775</option>
            <option value="1875">1875</option>
            <option value="1975">1975</option>
            <option value="2075">2075</option>
            <option value="2175">2175</option>
            <option value="2275">2275</option>
            <option value="2375">2375</option>
            <option value="2475">2475</option>
            <option value="2575">2575</option>
            <option value="2675">2675</option>
            <option value="2775">2775</option>
            <option value="2875">2875</option>
            <option value="2975">2975</option>
            <option value="3075">3075</option>
            <option value="3175">3175</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Insert Another Row</button><br><br>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function displayResult() {
    document.getElementById("lst-table").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>'
  }
</script>
```

Below is an image of how the table currently looks.

[Product Ordering Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUzm8.jpg)

[image]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect we don't need to see your exact `<table>`, could you reduce the demo to - as a suggestion - three columns in order to demonstrate the problem? Obviously we need enough - but *only* enough - to see the problem you describe. Incidentally, I've converted your posted code to a running demo in the question, could you check that it's accurate, and edit if not? Though, again, a smaller demo would be appreciated.

Comment: First you need to check if it's your first time inserting, if it's your first time putting the line like you did, if not copy the last html line and use that for the new one.

Comment: Hi David, edited the code to a smaller demo. Yes your running demo works correctly. Looking to have it so when user clicks for another row it duplicates the dropdown cells. The context is that the user can select different colours, lengths etc for their product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
document.getElementById("lst-table").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = document.getElementById("lst-table").rows[1].innerHTML;
```

May be beneficial to ready up on jquery will make life a whole bunch easier.

Comment: Hi Krik, your solution worked brilliantly, thank you for taking the time to provide this. Was looking at a similar question that did this with jquery as you suggested which I might look into more as a future solution / to optimise the current solution further. Thanks again!